# Can 'disposition' in the sense defined below relate to inanimate objects?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

A disposition is defined as "a natural tendency to do something, or to have or develop something" [[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disposition)].

For example;

> *A book has the ability to be opened.*

Is this specifying a disposition a book has?

If not,  what differentiates this type of statement from ones specifying dispositions?

Comment: You should include the definition (ideally from a authoritative dictionary) of what you understand a disposition to be.

Comment: The relevant definition in the ***full*** Oxford English Dictionary is **disposition** (6) - *Natural tendency or bent of the **mind**, esp. in relation to **moral** or **social** qualities; **mental** constitution or **temperament**; turn of **mind*** (emphasis mine). Books don't have minds or morals, so it would be a ***very*** figurative usage.

Comment: I'd say that reasonable research here looks at the example sentences recognised dictionaries add. Are there _any_ (for this sense of 'disposition') that do not indicate that this word must refer to a sentient being?

Comment: An *ability* is not a *tendency*. A book might possibly have a tendency to fall open at a certain page; but simply being able to be opened can't count as a "natural tendency".

Comment: @Andrew Leach Yes; I added 'potential' but it changes the question too much (improving it, but the original misapprehension needs addressing). 'Propensity' doesn't need a sentient referent (about half a million hits on Google for "propensity to explode", not many seeming to be figurative).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *disposition* can be used to describe the tendency of an inanimate object to have or develop a state. That is a wonky usage though. *Oxford English Dictionary*, "disposition, n." definition 9a describes this:

> Physical aptitude, tendency, or inclination (to something, or to do something).
>
> ...
> 1654   Z. Coke Art of Logick 32   Disposition..sometimes it is largely used for all fitness to any thing..as when water waxeth warm, it is said to have a **disposition** to heat.

?1791   W. Hamilton tr. C.-L. Berthollet Elements Art of Dyeing I. i. ii. i. 120   The different **dispositions** of wool, silk, etc. to unite with the colouring particles.

In those examples, water and wool have dispositions to specific states or actions: heat or bonding with dye.

More contemporary examples also tend to refer to materials:

> The **disposition** of normally ductile materials to fail in a brittle manner is discussed in Section 8.6. (*[Callister's Materials Science and Engineering](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Callister_s_Materials_Science_and_Engine/IUjODwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=material%20science%20AND%20disposition&pg=PA484&printsec=frontcover)*, 2020, p. 229)

Again, we have an object (normally ductile materials) that have a *disposition* to brittleness under certain conditions. *Disposition* can also be used more abstractly to label a book's mode or approach:

> The **disposition** of the book is pedagogic (Rédei, A. C. (2014). [Review of Language, music, and the brain: A mysterious relationship](https://doi.org/10.1037/pmu0000059). *Psychomusicology: Music, Mind, and Brain*, 24(3), 255–263.)

So you can describe a particular tendency of the book as a *disposition*. Just know that the usage hits a high academic register and may strike readers as peculiar.